# Flask SQLAlchemy connection via Proxy

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, proxy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Database hosted on a private server which I am using to interact with a frontend website. To access the database my IP needs whitelisting. My website is hosted on Heroku and it's IP's are not static, so I've configured it to take all traffic via a proxy server which does have a static IP.

In setting my database connection via SQLAlchemy, I need to tell it to go via the proxy address. Is there a way to configure this?

I tried:

```
proxy = "..."
os.environ['http_proxy'] = proxy
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = proxy
os.environ['https_proxy'] = proxy
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = proxy


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '....'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'mysql://{USER}:{PASS}@{HOST}:{PORT}/{DB}'
.......
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Getting connection time out when live in production.

Can SQLAlchemy library deal with setting proxy's? I've looked through documentation and cannot find anything. Maybe there is a trick I'm missing?

Comment: I don't think SQLAlchemy distinguishes between proxy and non-proxy addresses: they are just addresses.  Are you able to connect to the server from the Heroku command line?

Answer (score 0):

The system-level HTTP/HTTP proxy settings won't work for proxying a connection to a MySQL database. That database connection is a TCP connection, but it does not involve HTTP or HTTPS requests and thus those system-level proxy settings won't have any effect.

However, it is possible to proxy a database connection over a [SOCKS proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS). Some database drivers support this natively, but SQLAlchemy does not. Instead, you can use an executable like [fixie-wrench](https://usefixie.com/documentation/fixie-wrench/) or [ncat](https://nmap.org/ncat/guide/ncat-proxy.html) to forward a local port over a SOCKS5 proxy.